# Is this wire safe to cut?

Tags: wiring

[image]It’s in a bedroom closet. I was hoping to just cut it with scissors. Also does anyone know what type of wire this is? [image]

Comment: It looks like coax cable to me, but the head-on photo makes it hard to determine. Can you take another picture of the end at an angle to better show the connector?

Comment: I added another picture. Kind of looks like sushi lol, there’s a bunch of cotton or fuzz(?) surrounding what looks like a single thread of copper

Comment: Yes, it's some kind of coax. Coax normally has a central main wire which is surrounded by a thick layer of insulation (usually plastic of some sort) and then a thin metal skin (often braided thin bare wires or aluminum foil) surrounding that insulation before the final outer layer of tough protective material.

Comment: "I was hoping to just cut it with scissors." Not gonna happen. You'll need a decent (or at least "okay-ish") set of wire cutters. A pair of "miracle cuts anything scissors" _might_ do the job. Save yourself the heartache and hassle, though, and pick up a pair of wire cutters (or "diagonal cutters") at the hardware store (just ask the sales guy, he'll point you in the right direction) while you're there getting the blank face plate. You'll find _all_ sorts of uses for them in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's low voltage and perfectly safe to handle.

Go ahead and remove the 2 screws on the junction box cover.  Look to see if there is a screw-on coupler inside the box.  If there is, then uncouple it there, then get a blank cover plate at the hardware store. Done & dusted.

I expect that will be the case.

If it's just cable coming out, then cut it so there is about 1 foot free coming out of the wall, and then coil it up inside the box and cover it with a blank cover plate.

You'll thank me later lol.

Feel free to label the blank cover "CATV".

if you ever get cable or satellite again, point out this box and the cable guy will be like "Wow, that saves me a whole bunch of tearing up your house and doing unsightly, lazy cable work!"

Comment: Just what I wanted to know, and more! Thank you very much, this helps out a lot. I will follow your steps this weekend

Answer (score 3):

Looks like CoAx for a cable service. You can cut it (you'll probably need more than scissors). For me, the clues are the end of the cable, plus the nasty way screws are just ran through the faceplate (very similar to XFinity's installation quality)

Comment: Ah interesting, that’s good to know about the cable. I bet the previous owner was using Xfinity then. And you were right about the screws! I just tested the faceplate and it about fell off lol

Comment: Any and every cable provider will use cable like this, it's not just Xfinity/Comcast. Most cable companies probably use the same contractors for installation. Even satellite TV will get the signal from the dish into the house using coax cable like this. Let's not pick on Xfinity, it's _all_ of them that do less than stellar work! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a TV cable.

Push it back in the wall as much it goes (you might need it later.)

Cut it and tape the end making sure the middle wire does not touch the outside mesh, otherwise you will short it.

There is no electricity in it to worry about.

Comment: Perfect! I was worried about there being electricity but I now know there’s not - thank you for your help!!